# Azure CLI: az devops configure --defaults... has no effect. What am I missing?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am using Azure CLI azure-devops extension to manage my projects and git repositories in dev.azure.com.

```
az extension add --name azure-devops
```

To make code more readable and configurable I would like to use: (it does not matter if the values are between quotation marks or not)

```
az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/myname
az devops configure --defaults project=f514a982-...
```

Those commands executed without error (powershell) but it seems they has no effect on the following commands.

For example

```
az repos list # lists an other project's repos, not the required f514a982
```

However executing

```
az repos list --project f514a982....
```

gives the expected result.

Missing I something or is this a bug?

Comment: Actually I figured it out if anyone interested: There is a --detect  parameter which is 'on' by default and if it is 'on' then overrules the --defaults settings. So if you run anywhere the command under a git repo folder tree and you do not explicitly use the --detect off, it will use that project (as default) which that git repo belongs to regardless of the previously executed az devops configure --defaults.. command

Comment: You add it as an answer and mark it that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I figured it out, hopefully spares time someone in the future:

There is a `--detect` parameter which is `on` by default and if it is `on` then overrules the `--defaults` settings.

So if you run *anywhere* the command under a git repo folder tree and you do not *explicitly* use the `--detect off`, it will use that devops project (as default) which that git repo belongs to regardless of the previously executed `az devops configure --defaults` command

Comment: So did you have to use `--detect off` on all az devops commands are just the ones in a git repo?

Comment: Checked it out myself, had to put `--detect false` on every single command.  Kind of annoying.